# Is there a way to use Translation Overview with Entity Translation?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

When I use the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module with [Translation Overview](https://www.drupal.org/project/translation_overview) all works fine, I can see through `admin/content/translation-overview-manage` the state of the translations of nodes.

But when I use [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) I can't see this information. I've been searching for some info on the net, but I can't find anything about this.

So, is there a way to use Translation Overview in combination with Entity Translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should consider switching from the [Translation Overview](https://www.drupal.org/project/translation_overview) module to the [Translation Management Tool](https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt) module, which allows all Drupal text elements to be used as source for translation. I.e. Nodes, Entities, I18n Strings (Menu, Terms etc.).

That's also what seems to comply with what is written on the Translation Overview project page, i.e.:

> ... The superseding Translation management (TMGMT) module was initiated with Drupal 7 and is already well ported to Drupal 8. We highly recommend it - already with Drupal 7.

Comment: Great! Curious to hear later on how it turned out (fingers crossed) ... And just in case you don't know/realize: @berdir should know way more about the tmgmt module. Maybe he'll also follow how this evolves. Would be nice if he would join the conversation some day to share his experience about all this ...